# How to fix Xamarin Forms pipeline Target Framework error

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Locally, I can build and run my Xamarin Forms application with no issues. In my Azure build pipelines I have my master branch failing because of my target framework version. It says it is 9.0 when it should be at least 10.0.

In my Android project file I have the framework version set to 10.0. I have made sure it is also v10 in the properties tab for the project. Yet I still get the below error.

```
##[error]C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2012\build\Xamarin.Forms.targets(188,5): Error XF005: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for MyApp.Android (v9.0) is less than the minimum required $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms (10.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for MyApp.Android.
```

Answer (score 1):

Verify that BOTH of the following project properties are set to 10.0:

Application / Compile using Android version (Target Framework).

Android Manifest / Target Android version.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels

If those are already both 10.0, then make sure the Azure build pipeline has up-to-date versions of Android SDKs and tools.

---

Another way to fix:

If you are able to create a new sample solution, and successfully build that via Azure, then start a new solution, and add all your files to it.

Comment: I checked and confirmed both the above have API Level 29 or v10. I am pretty new with Azure pipelines... I am looking at the Xamarin.Android build task I cannot find anything to do with Android SDKs and tools. Can you please offer some guidance with this please? I really appreciate this

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using Azure. It sounds like you have done everything "right" in your project; I was just guessing it might be something missing/out-of-date on the Azure side. If you create a new empty sample project, and send it to Azure, does it work?

Comment: Turns out I was using a build configuration which had `v9.0` and not `v10.0` which was my local build config. Thanks Steve. Guess I was not doing the right thing after all

Answer (score 1):

Try to open your `.csproj` file,and manually modify its targetFrameworkVersion.

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v10.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Comment: Hi, I already did this and still have had no luck. My .csproj file says v10.0

Comment: Did you try to delete the obj and bin files and rebuild it ?

Comment: Turns out I was using a build configuration which had `v9.0` and not `v10.0` which was my local build config. Thanks Leo